# How to check if Mysql Time Field is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm new to programming and trying to make a timesheet work. My problem is that no matter what I try, I can't get my PHP to check if the value in my DB on endWork is set or NULL. (It is null as of right now)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['setTimestamp'])) {
$date = $_POST['date'];
$workDate = date('Y-m-d');


$dateQuery = "SELECT WorkDate FROM WorkingHours WHERE WorkDate = 
'$workDate'";
$eWorkQuery = "SELECT EndWork FROM WorkingHours WHERE WorkDate = 
'$workDate'";
$eBreakQuery = "SELECT EndBreak FROM WorkingHours WHERE WorkDate = 
'$workDate'";
$sBreakQuery = "SELECT StartBreak FROM WorkingHours WHERE WorkDate = 
'$workDate'";
$sWorkQuery = "SELECT StartWork FROM WorkingHours WHERE WorkDate = 
'$workDate'";


$d_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $dateQuery);
$e_w_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $eWorkQuery);
$e_b_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $eBreakQuery);
$s_b_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sBreakQuery);
$s_w_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $sWorkQuery);


if (mysqli_num_rows($d_query_run)==1) {

    if (!isset($e_w_query_run)) {

        if (empty($e_b_query_run)) {

            if (empty($s_b_query_run)) {

                if (empty($s_w_query_run)) {
                }
                else{
                    echo " set StartBreak's time to localtime ";
                }


            }
            else{
                echo " set EndBreak's time to localtime ";
            }


        }
        else{
            echo " set EndWork's time to localtime ";
        }


    }

    else{
        echo " You already submited your timesheet for today ";
        echo "<pre>" ,print_r($e_w_query_run, TRUE),"</pre>";
    }


}
else{
    echo " set StartWork's time to localtime";
}

}
?>
```

The code line below is only to check the output of my query.

```
echo "<pre>" ,print_r($e_w_query_run, TRUE),"</pre>";
```

I've tried it with `!isset() is_null empty()`. 
Mostly it tells me that it can't use those Operations on an Object but instead on an Array. Because of that, I tried it with `mysqli_fetch_array` but that also didn't work.

It would be awesome if someone could help me out with that, and also thanks in advance.

Comment: try dumping $_POST['setTimestamp'] to see what's actually in there. Maybe you should try http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip i'll give it a shot right away. The problem's already solved thanks to Igor Ilic, but it's always good to have a closer look into what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just running `mysqli_query` won't give you your data. In order to access it you need to do something like this:

```
$qyery = mysqli_query($con, $eWorkQuery);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if(is_null($result['EndWork'])){
  echo " set EndBreak's time to localtime "; 
}
```

or if you want to use objects

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
if(is_null($result->EndWork)){
  echo " set EndBreak's time to localtime "; 
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much it worked right away when i tried it with your first suggestion. I guess i messed something up when I tried it with mysqli_fetch_array before.